# How to make proper anchor tags when angular route is active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to set up some anchor tags for a template, which gets modified by `angular route`and has the following url scheme:

```
main.html#/view/:name
```

I tried to ignore angular's routing by setting the `target` attribute:

```
 <a target="_self" href="#some_anchor">Go to anchor</a>
```

however, the actual link now is `main.html#/some_anchor`, and omitting `target=_self`doesn't change anything.
I then tried to change the links target to the actual current url with

```
$location.path() + "/#some_anchor"
```

which doesn't work either (no matter if I set `target`attribute or not), I still get a "Page not found" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make this workaround in the same situation:

Define function in scope:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function (id) {
    var old = $location.hash();
    $location.hash(id);
    $anchorScroll();
    $location.hash(old);
};
```

And call it this way:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="scrollTo('anchor')">Scroll to anchor</a>
```

Comment: This works, is this possible with dynamically created elements as well?
Something like `content += "\<li><a ng-click=\"scrollTo("+text+")\" >"+text+"\</a>"+ "\</li>"` ?

Comment: It depends. Speaking of AngularJs I doubt if you doing it right treating template this way. What exactly do you do?

Comment: I implemented dynamically generated table of contents. I eventually solved the dynamical part by combining your solution with `.preventDefault` to read out the text of the clicked link first and then pass that text to 'your' function. Works pretty well.